# How to run two meteor apps simultaneously

Tags: meteor

When I run a second meteor application, I get the following message:

> Can't listen on port 3000. Perhaps another Meteor is running?
>
> Running two copies of Meteor in the same application directory
> will not work. If something else is using port 3000, you can
> specify an alternative port with --port .

Answer (score 4):

To start meteor on a different port (eg 3002) just run:

```
meteor --port 3002
```

In the project directory.